# "netlink error: Operation not permitted" running Zeek on Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ids, zeek

I'm running Zeek on a Docker container (from image Zeekurity) in standalone mode and I'm trying to disable checksum offloading for my network interface, but then this happens:

```
root@0787148fac96:/usr/local/zeek# ethtool --offload eth0 rx off tx off
netlink error: Operation not permitted`
```

I really can't understand why.

Zeek version is 2.7.1, container's OS is Linux 11,
Docker version is 20.10.17 running on Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS 64 bit

Comment: A typical Docker container has intentionally limited privileges. You can drop all restrictions with the `--privileged` flag, or add specific capabilities with `--cap-add` (such as `--cap-add NET_ADMIN`). See